# Two Dimensional Array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having troubles with my "for" loop in my program. The main error I am getting is "type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Boolean." All I want to do is to have the corresponding "time" element printed out. I know that conditions need to be of type bool for "classNames[0].length", but I can't figure out how to do that. Thanks!

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class arraytest {
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    int i = 0;
    String classInput;

    String[][] classNames = {
              {"CIS 280", "ACC 212", "HIS 300"},
              {"Tue 7:30", "Thu 2:30", "Fri 1:00" }
            };


classInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input a class name: ");


for (i = 0; classNames[0].length; ++i) // problem line
   if(classNames[0][i].equals(classInput)) 
   {
       System.out.println("class time:" + classNames[1][i]);

   }
}
```

}

Comment: `classNames[0].length;` Doesn't mean anything as a condition. You probably want `i < classNames[0].length;`. You might want to read up on how for loops work.

Comment: Well, error is saying the truth `classNames[0].length` is not boolean. You probably wanted `i < classNames[0].length`.

Comment: If you really want to convert int to boolean, (<int>!=0) will do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You probably wanted to compare `i` to `classNames[0].length` to provide the necessary `boolean` argument.  Providing just `classNames[0].length` is just an `int`.

```
for (i = 0; i < classNames[0].length; ++i)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you meant:

```
for (i = 0; i < classNames[0].length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class arraytest {
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    int i = 0;
    String classInput;

    String[][] classNames = {
              {"CIS 280", "ACC 212", "HIS 300"},
              {"Tue 7:30", "Thu 2:30", "Fri 1:00" }
            };


classInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input a class name: ");


for (i = 0; i<classNames[0].length; ++i) // problem line
   if(classNames[0][i].equals(classInput)) 
   {
       System.out.println("class time:" + classNames[1][i]);

   }
}

}
```

this will solve your error you just forgot the i<